# Subscribed to collections are empty on Client

Tags: meteor, iron-router

So I'm using iron-router with meteor in order to wait for a collection subscribe before loading the page.  This is my routing code

`this.route('Report', {
        waitOn : function() {
                return Meteor.subscribe('channel_history_device',this.params.id);
        },
        loadingTemplate : 'loading',
        onRun : function() {
            Session.set('selectedItemId',this.params.id);
        },
        action : function() {
            if(this.ready())
                this.render();
        },
        path: '/Details/:id'
    });`

Heres my publish:

`Meteor.publish('channel_history_device' , function(itemId){
    console.log('count of publish '+ChannelsHistory.find().count());

    return ChannelsHistory.find();
});`

On when the page loads.  The Console log on the server end will return a count > 1 however the collection on the client will always be empty.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. `loadingTemplate` is used by the `loading` hook, do you use that hook or not? Do you have `Router.onBeforeAction('loading')` anywhere in your code?

Comment: I do not.  I read [here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/265) that you need it for the waitOn to actually work.

Comment: So if you add `Router.onBeforeAction('loading')` and remove your custom `action` in the route, does it work as you wish?